# mobile quiz app in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I would like to create a mobile app that has a quiz. The quiz would pull information from a web server so that the quiz can be updated. Can this be done in just HTML5 and jQuery? If so are there any tuts you recommend? I am lost.

Comment: You'll need something on the server to communicate with your JS. PHP? Look into [AJAX](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/)

Comment: phonegap should be an easy way to do this. check it out here http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned , you will need some server side infrastructure to make AJAX calls from your mobile web application to retrieve the questions and also to store results,etc if you want.

For what you want to do, HTML5 and jQueryMobile are well suited to the task.

For some simple tutorials on using basic HTML5 Canvas stuff to create puzzle/quiz in HTML5, here are some links:

- http://www.flashbynight.com/tutes/html5quiz/
- http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2012/08/01/tutorial-puzzle-game-basics-with-html5-and-javascript/